# Gurobi with python dictionary key value error

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, optimization, gurobi

I am using Gurobi 7 with Python 2.7 and want to implement the following linear optimization problem:

[image]

I have translated the above to Python and Gurobi using the following code:

```
    T = range(1,17520)
    # Create variables - defined as dictionaries
    p = {} # power
    s = {} # SOC
    b = {} # buy

    for t in T:
        p[t] = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = -R, ub = R, name = "power_{}".format(t))
        s[t] = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0, ub = E, name = "SOC_{}".format(t))
        b[t] = m.addVar(vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0, name = "Buy_{}".format(t))                                

    # constraints
    for t in T:
        m.addConstr(b[t] == demand[t] + p[t], name = "balance_{}".format(t))
        if t == 0:
            m.addConstr(s[t] == p[t], name = "charge_{}".format(t))
        else:
            m.addConstr(s[t] == s[t-1] + p[t], name = "charge_{}".format(t))

    # integrate variables and constraints
    m.update()

    # Objective function
    obj = quicksum(
        b[t]*SBP[t] 
        for t in T
    )
    m.setObjective(obj,GRB.MINIMIZE)

    # start optimization
    m.optimize
```

The error message I get (shown below) is probably due to the [t-1] index; however I do not see why this is not accepted by the compiler. Do I need to define this constraints in a different way?

[image: error message]

I have not found any other examples of gurobi optimization problems being defined with this structure (variable is a function of the preceding variable etc.) but this is a very typical structure for LP problems.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK turns out I was confused with Python's zero-indexing; I have defined the set T as a range from 1 to 17520 and yet I subsequently define constraints for variables indexed in 0.

My problem was fixed by defining the set T as

```
    T = range(0,17519)
```